# how to convert in a json format and obtain jsonobject from json array

Tags: android, json

```
[{"id":0,"date":"4 - 0 - 1900","subject":"dfhjkjdfhgd","desc":"dfgbjdfiobhfh"},{"id":1,"date":"12
- 0 - 1900","subject":"4564546","desc":"fdghsdfhbrtfh"},{"id":2,"date":"6 - 0 - 1900","subject":"gfgjfcghnf","desc":"fgbnfgh"},{"id":3,"date":"11
- 0 - 1900","subject":"fgjhnfgjhnfg","desc":"fghfhn"}]
```

This is the string i have to parse json objects in json array.Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: your question is duplicated. see this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON or Jackson to parse JSON array

Example:

`Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonOutput = response;
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<your_POJO_class>>(){}.getType();
 List<your_POJO_class> mylist = (List<your_POJO_class>)gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);`

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground

```
JSONArray response;    
response = new JSONArray(responseString); // responseString is your Value

String ID[];
String Date[];
String Subject[];
String Desc[];
```

In OnPostExecute

```
ID= new String[response.length()];
Date = new String[response.length()];
Subject = new String[response.length()];
Desc = new String[response.length()];
for(int i = 0 , count = response.length(); i < count ; i++ )
{
  try
  {
   JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
   ID[i] = jObj.getString("id");
   Date[i] = jObj.getString("date");
   Subject[i] = jObj.getString("subject");
   Desc[i] = jObj.getString("desc");
  }
  catch(JSONException e)
  {}
}
```